# Get list of people syncing from certain SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sync

I want to ask, is there a way for getting a list of folders that are synced in local machines for a specific SharePoint site?, with the accounts that did this syncing?

Or can we get the syncing activities log so we detect these activates

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to get inforamtion about synced folders in the local machines.

For synchronization activities logs, you could go to Microsoft 365 compliance ->  Audit -> In the Audit log search page, choose Synchronization Activities in Activities -> In the File, folder, or site section, enter the site URL.

[image]